# Rails Devise - How to authenticate user inside initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, external

A rails app using external [coupon gem](https://github.com/fnando/coupons) and devise to block coupon pages from being used from non-admin user. in my initializer/coupons.rb trying to do something like this:

```
  config.authorizer = proc do |controller|
      if !current_user.admin?

        redirect_to(request.referrer || "/")
      end
  end
```

getting this one:
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for main:Object

Having a look at the [application controller's gem](https://github.com/fnando/coupons/blob/master/app/controllers/coupons/application_controller.rb) shows authorizer initializer call in before action filter.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to reference user on models/initializers break the MVC architeture principles. The logic about the current_user should be in controllers and views. Consider refactoring your logic, please. Thanks!